# docker nginx load balancer connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to load balance a simple Nodejs app with 3 instances using docker-compose & nginx. This configuration works on my local machine (windows laptop) but doesn't seem to work on EC2 server.

nginx.conf

```
http {

upstream all {
    server nodeapp1:4100;
    server nodeapp2:4200;
    server nodeapp3:4300;
}

server {
     listen 8080;
     location / {
          proxy_pass http://all/;
     }
}

}

events { }
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

 services:
  lb:
  image: nginx
 volumes:
    - ./nginxproxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ports:
    - "3000:8080"
nodeapp1:
 image: nodeapp
 environment:
  - PORT=4100
 ports:
  - "4100:4100"
 nodeapp2:
  image: nodeapp
  environment:
  - PORT=4200
 ports:
  - "4200:4200"
 nodeapp3:
  image: nodeapp
  environment:
  - PORT=4300
  ports:
  - "4300:4300"
```

I'm new to docker. I'm surprised why this works locally but does not work on EC2 instance. The load balancer was able to resolve the url correctly but it still says connection refused.

Error:

```
2022/02/28 20:00:22 [error] 33#33: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
 connecting to upstream, client: 62.113.237.40, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
 upstream: "http://172.121.0.5:4100/", host: "18.121.121.23:3000"
```

Comment: On further analysis, I think the root cause is that my apps are listening to localhost where as NGINX is forwarding requests to the internal IP address of the containers. I think the solution is to either make NGINX forward to localhost of EC2 server (not localhost of NGINX container) or make the apps listen to the host of docker containers internal ip address.

Answer (score 0):

For me service name or ip address not worked, only work put the gateway IP of network, for default bridge is 172.17.0.1.

In the servers put the (gateway ip):(port of container) and with this haproxy connects with success.

My example of custom network with fixed ips and gateway:

---- nginx config

```
upstream loadbalancer {
  server 172.17.0.1:8001 weight=5;
  server 172.17.0.1:8002 weight=5;
}
```

----- haproxy config similar

```
backend be_pe_8545
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin

    server p1 172.20.0.254:18545 check inter 10s
    server p2 172.20.0.254:28545 check inter 10s
```

----- docker app / network

```
  docker_app: ... 
    networks:
      public_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.50 

  public_network:
    name: public_network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet:  172.20.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.20.0.254
```